# SQL Query for Deserialized XML

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, xml

I am trying to create a sql query in C# that will transfer my data from my xml file to the sql server.  I am successfully able to deserialize my XML into a "get, set" methods and output my xml into the console.  I have been searching Google for the past day to find how to create a insert query to add my xml into my sql table.  Here is what I have so far for both my classes.  Class1 is my "get, set" method class, and Program is my "main" method class.

Class1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static object Item_ID { get; set; }
        public static object Invent_id { get; set; }
        public static object Itemsize { get; set; }
        public static object Color { get; set; }
        public static decimal Curr_price { get; set; }
        public static object Qoh { get; set; }
    }
    public class transactions
    {
        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "UPDATE")]
        public class UPDATE
        {
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "qoh")]
            public string Qoh { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "curr_price")]
            public string Curr_price { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "color")]
            public string Color { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "itemsize")]
            public string Itemsize { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "invent_id")]
            public string Invent_id { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "item_id")]
            public string Item_id { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "ADD")]
        public class ADD
        {
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "qoh")]
            public string Qoh { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "curr_price")]
            public string Curr_price { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "color")]
            public string Color { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "itemsize")]
            public string Itemsize { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "invent_id")]
            public string Invent_id { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "item_id")]
            public string Item_id { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "DELETE")]
        public class DELETE
        {
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "item_id")]
            public string Item_id { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "transactions")]
        public class Transactions
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "UPDATE")]
            public UPDATE UPDATE { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "ADD")]
            public List<ADD> ADD { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "DELETE")]
            public DELETE DELETE { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Main Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string conString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver};"
                + "Server=XXX;Port=YYY;"
                + "Database=inventory;"
                + "uid=ZZZ;pwd=XYZ";
            OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(conString);

            {
                XDocument theFile = XDocument.Load("C:\\Users\\Bob\\Documents\\Update.xml");

                foreach (XElement el in theFile.Root.Elements())
                {
                    if (el.Name == "ADD")
                    {
                       Console.WriteLine("{0}   {1}   {2}   {3}   {4}   {5}   {6}", el.Name, el.Attribute("qoh").Value, el.Attribute("curr_price").Value, el.Attribute("color").Value, el.Attribute("itemsize").Value, el.Attribute("invent_id").Value, el.Attribute("item_id").Value);
                       Console.ReadLine();

                        OdbcCommand Command1 = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO item (item_id, invent_id, itemsize, color, curr_price, qoh) VALUES( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ", connection);
                        Command1.Parameters.Add("@SZ", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = Class1.Itemsize;
                        Command1.Parameters.Add("@COL", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = Class1.Color;
                        Command1.Parameters.Add("@PR", OdbcType.Double).Value = (double)Class1.Curr_price;
                        Command1.Parameters.Add("@QOH", OdbcType.Int).Value = Class1.Qoh;
                        Command1.Parameters.Add("@ID", OdbcType.Int).Value = Class1.Item_ID;

                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                    else if (el.Name == "UPDATE")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}   {1}   {2}   {3}   {4}   {5}   {6}", el.Name, el.Attribute("qoh").Value, el.Attribute("curr_price").Value, el.Attribute("color").Value, el.Attribute("itemsize").Value, el.Attribute("invent_id").Value, el.Attribute("item_id").Value);
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                    else if (el.Name == "DELETE")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}   {1}", el.Name, el.Attribute("item_id").Value);
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Update:

In regards to using MySQL LOAD query, here is what I have but am not sure if it is correct.  After reading your link about Infile Loading, it seems I just point the query to the xml file location and it will copy the data into the fields in my SQL table.  I also changed the parameters in the correct order and still does not work.  It seems it is not seeing the values from my xml file or my parameter line is not correct.

```
 OdbcCommand Command1 = new OdbcCommand("LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Users\\Bob\\Documents\\Update.xml' INTO TABLE item ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<ADD>'");
```

Comment: MySQL 5.5+ supports LOAD XML read ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html )

Comment: Add parameters in the same order as they appear in the INSERT statement.

Comment: Am I missing an execute reader line?  Is this needed if using LOAD XML INFILE?

Comment: When I run my line from my "Update" post within MySQL, it works fine.  But not in my c# script...

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to use Load XML with my query.  I noticed that the file path needed "/", not "\" as it could not read the file.  After making this change, it work.  Below is my edited code.

```
if (el.Name == "ADD")
                    {
                       Console.WriteLine("Item {0} ", el.Attribute("invent_id").Value + " was successfully added.");
                        Console.ReadLine();

                        OdbcCommand Command1 = new OdbcCommand("LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/Adam/Documents/Update.xml' INTO TABLE item ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<ADD>'", connection);
                        connection.Open();
                        OdbcDataReader reader = Command1.ExecuteReader();
                        connection.Close();
                    }
```